# Is there a Dev Container “Features” for rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb, devcontainer

I’ve been looking for a [Dev Container “Features”](https://containers.dev/implementors/features/) for rethinkdb, since I tried [GitHub’s dev containers](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/introduction-to-dev-containers) for in-browser development.

I haven’t found one and without, I have to install Rethinkdb every time.

**Has someone already made a dev container feature for Rethinkdb or do I have to create one myself?**